# Pack installed system in tar.gz file

Tags: backup, tar, restore

I have arch linux installed, with partition scheme like this:

```
/dev/mapper/lvm-root -> /
/dev/mapper/lvm-home -> /home
/dev/mapper/lvm-opt  -> /opt
/dev/mapper/lvm-pkg  -> /var/cache/pacman/pkg
```

With that, I will boot to archlinux live CD and do the following:

```
mount /dev/mapper/lvm-root /mnt
tar -czvf arch-root.tar.gz /mnt
umount /mnt

mount /dev/mapper/lvm-home /mnt
tar -czvf arch-home.tar.gz /mnt
umount /mnt

mount /dev/mapper/lvm-opt /mnt
tar -czvf arch-opt.tar.gz /mnt
umount /mnt

mount /dev/mapper/lvm-pkg /mnt
tar -czvf arch-pkg.tar.gz /mnt
umount /mnt
```

And then, I will back up those packages, clean up the disk with new partition scheme (possibly not lvm), install windows at first partition on the disk, and unpack those packages to the partition after windows partition. For boot, I will do `grub-install` with archlinux CD.

My question is, will this gonna work?

Comment: You're better off using something like fsarchiver, I'd say. That will save the contents of a filesystem for you, and then unpack it again wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, with some caveats. For one thing, beware of differing FS UUIDs; modern distros often list mounts in `/etc/fstab` via UUID, which won't survive making new FS and untarring (though it might survive a `dd` straight from one block device to the other). For another, you'll need to re-tweak GRUB to make it boot, making sure to give the proper `set root` and `root=` options to GRUB and the kernel respectively.

Also, the literal command lines you posted will include the paths in the `tar.gz` files including a prefixing `/mnt`, which is likely not what you want. To avoid this, instead of `tar -czvf <filename> /mnt`, do `cd /mnt; tar -czvf .`. (Otherwise, you'd find yourself untarring them and getting everything under `/mnt` on the new volumes.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes; that is exactly how you backup and restore a system.